# Usage of instanceof operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Can someone explain why does this code snippet returns result as "false"

```
function f(){ return f; }
new f() instanceof f;
```

As per my understanding instanceof checks the current object and returns true if the object is of the specified object type.

So "new f()" should act as a current object and it is an instance of type f.
Consequently result should be true.

Comment: remove the return statement and then try

Comment: But your constructor returns a different object that is not an instance of the constructor in any sense.

Answer (score 2):

`new function()` does [much more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) than *invoking the constructor and returning its output*.

> It creates a new object. The type of this object is simply object.
>
> It sets this new object's internal, inaccessible, [[prototype]] (i.e.
>   **proto**) property to be the constructor function's external, accessible, prototype object (every function object automatically has
>   a prototype property).
>
> It makes the this variable point to the newly created object.
>
> It executes the constructor function, using the newly created object
>   whenever this is mentioned.
>
> **It returns the newly created object, unless the constructor function
>   returns a non-null object reference. In this case, that object
>   reference is returned instead**.

However, if the function's constructor already returns a value, then output of `new function()` is same as `function()`

```
function f1(){ return f1 }
f1() == new f1() //returns true
```

Without `return` statement in constructor

```
function f1(){ }
f1() == new f1() //returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the return f. New will give you an object unless you return something else, in this case the function f.